# Getting the user by password reset token in Laravel without explicitly writing SQL query

Tags: laravel

I am developing a Laravel application. Now, I am trying to customise the password reset feature. I am trying to get the user by password reset token. I looked at the underlying database schema. There is a table called, password_resets. It has email, token and created_at columns. I can get the email of the user by token from that table. The thing is since there is no model created for that table, I will have to write the SQL query manually like this.

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM password_resets WHERE token=?', [ $token ])
```

or the query builder

```
DB::table('password_resets')->where('token',$token)->first();
```

But I am trying to avoid using manual query. Is there a way to get the user by password reset token without writing manual SQL query?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the methods inside the [`DatabaseTokenRepository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php). Not sure if that's the sort of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
DB::table('password_resets')->where('token',$token)->first();
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question. I do not want to use the query builder too.

Comment: I just used this for now since this is a lot better than using manual query.